# Setting boundary for PanGesture for imageView

Tags: ios, swift, uigesturerecognizer, uipangesturerecognizer

I am working on emoji photo app that users can add an emoji on the photos from their phone and share it on Instagram and more.

Users can zoom, rotate, and drag emojis to anywhere they want to decorate photos and I want to set the boundary so that emoji can't be dragged outside photo. Currently setting boundary seems to work except when user drags emoji fast (swiping fast) - emoji can be dragged outside photo and disappear completely. I am attaching my code for handlePan and screenshot of the app.

Can anyone see why/how emoji can move outside boundary when user drags it fast? Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
@IBAction func handlePan(recognizer:UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    if(deleteMode) {
        return
    }

    let translation = recognizer.translationInView(self.view)
    var centerX: CGFloat!
    var centerY: CGFloat!
    var ipadLeftBoundary: CGFloat!

    if let view = recognizer.view {

        if(is_ipad) {
            ipadLeftBoundary = 55
        } else {
            ipadLeftBoundary = 0
        }

        print("panelBackground.frame.origin.x: \(panelBackground.frame.origin.x)")
        print("view.center.x: \(view.center.x)")
        print("panelBackground.frame.origin.y: \(panelBackground.frame.origin.y)")
        print("view.center.y: \(view.center.y)")
        print("panelBackground width: \(panelBackground.frame.size.width)")

        // setting boundary for x
        if(view.center.x + translation.x < panelBackground.frame.origin.x - ipadLeftBoundary) {
            centerX = view.center.x + translation.x + 20
        } else if(view.center.x > panelBackground.frame.size.width){
            centerX = view.center.x + translation.x - 20
        } else {
            centerX = view.center.x + translation.x
        }
        // setting boundary for y
        if(view.center.y + 20 < panelBackground.frame.origin.y - 60){
            centerY = view.center.y + translation.y + 20
        } else if(view.center.y > panelBackground.frame.size.height){
            centerY = view.center.y + translation.y - 20
        } else {
            centerY = view.center.y + translation.y
        }

        // set final position
        view.center = CGPoint(x:centerX, y:centerY)
        recognizer.setTranslation(CGPointZero, inView: self.view)

    }
}
```

[screenshot of the app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qz4FA.png)